# Integrating semi dynamic website with a CMS

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, codeigniter, yii

Is it possible to integrate a semi-dynamic php website(which is technically made up of static pages sharing the same header, footer and sidebar) and a dynamic website(contact forms, polls, login, etc - made with either codeigniter, zend or yii)?

If so, what's the best way to do it? I'm talking about the dynamic website automatically generating the latest news, rss and table of contents from the semi-dynamic php.

I don't mind if I have to add XML generation, additional lines of codes or integrate the semi dynamic website to mysql database in order to integrate with the dynamic website, as long as it stays semi dynamic, in that the content(the articles written) of the semi-dynamic php website is still hardcoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the static website as a template in the frameworked one. This is different for each framework.

Comment: What do you mean by using static website as a template?

Comment: @Corbee one that is comprised mostly of static pages, as you described in your question. i.e, see http://book.cakephp.org/view/958/The-Pages-Controller

Answer (score 0):

Search for Yii's "pages" functionality - it's set up for pretty much what you are describing.